# How to duplicate expression specified number of times in one line in Mako

Tags: python, mako

I have this template:

```
% for n in range(1, max_n + 1):
    ${n}
% endfor
```

It'll be rendered this way: ( max_n = 3 )

```
1
2
3
```

I want these numbers to be in one line, like this:

```
1 2 3
```

How can I achieve this in Mako?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the template is in a python string you can just escape the newline with \\:

```py
from mako.template import Template

t = """
% for n in range(1, max_n + 1):
${n} \\
% endfor
"""

print(Template(t).render(max_n=3))
>>> 1 2 3
```